# What is the Prayachitta for not doing Sandhyavandanam regularly?

Tags: rituals, sandhyavandanam

If any twice born student is not doing Sandhyavandanam for many days, then only he realized the importance of Sandhyavandanam, how can he get rid of his sins for not doing Sandhyavandanam for many long years? What is the atone ritual for not doing Sandhyavandanam regularly?

Comment: To have new yagnopaveetam, take brahmopadesam again from acharya (or father), and do it regularly from now.

Comment: @ram Not for me. I just asked to clarify doubt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For many years is what you have mentioned. IMHO, in such cases, it will require another initiation but i am not quite sure on that.

The Manu Smriti says that such persons shall be treated just like Sudras (or non-initiates) are .

> Na tishtathi tu yah purvA na upAste yash cha pashchimam |
>  **Sa sudravad
>   vahishkAryah sarvasmAd dvijakarmanah** ||
>
> ...............
>
> But he who does not (worship) standing in the morning, nor sitting in
>   the evening, **shall be excluded, just like a Sudra, from all the
>   duties and rights of an Aryan.**
>
> **Manu Smriti 2.103**

Verses of similar nature are found elsewhere too:

> That Brahmana in particular, **who does not perform his Sandhya**
>   adorations, in the evening, morning and the noon, **becomes in his
>   lifetime like a S'udra**. After his death, he is born as a dog. (18)
>
> **One, who does not perform the Sandhya-adorations, is always impure,
>   and is unworthy of all religious rites**. The fruit, of any religious
>   rite that he may perform, goes not to him. (19)
>
> **Daksha Smriti Chapter 2 Verses.**

But, if it is a matter of failure for just a day, then remedies are are there and they are quite easy to perform too:

> He, who out of carelessness fails to perform the Sandhya once, either
>   in the morning or in the evening, should, with a concentrated mind,
>   recite, after bathing, the Gayatri for a thousand times. (63)
>
> **Atri Smriti**

Some hard-to-perform remedies (possibly for relatively more prolonged failures) are however prescribed in other Smritis like:

> In consequence of wilfully [neglecting the Sandhya, the foremost of
>   the twice-born should perform the distressing penance [of Prajapatya
>   for full one year, and should perform the Chandrayana, [if he does so]
>   for livelihood. [And] by making a gift of kine, [he is] purged of [his
>   sins]. (67)
>
> If he does so, prompted by agnosticism, a twice-born person should
>   perform the Prajapatya. By performing the Taptakrichha, one is purged
>   off of [the sin of] acting against the Deities and preceptors. (68)
>
> **Usana Smriti's Chapter 9 verses.**

Comment: What is Prajapatya,Chandrayana and Taptakriccha?

Comment: See Tryugi's answer here @Rāmachandra --- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/30293

Comment: Thank you so much Rickross ji !!!

Comment: I checked Auśanasī smr̥ti, it has just 51 ślokas and not 9 adhyāyas. It has only 1 adhyāya. Here's the pdf https://archive.org/details/ashtadash-smriti-18-smritis-pt.-sundar-lal-tripathi/page/n111/mode/2up?view=theater

Comment: The PDF I am quoting from has those verses in its 9th Chapter .. its a translation by M.N.Dutta @Bingming

Comment: Thanks, it seems the smr̥ti you quoted from, and the one I was searching, are different ones.