# What is the expiation for accidentally killing a cat?

Tags: karma, moksha

What is the expiation for accidentally killing a cat?

Comment: Kindly edit personal details from this and ask in general way.  Because personal advice type is not encouraged here!

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism se. Personal advice questions are not encouraged on this site. You may edit your question to suit the site rules. In any case you should ask a jyotish in your licality for advice or approach your family pujari if there is 1. There r attonements for such accidental deaths of animals.

Answer (score 5):

The *Dharma Shastras* prescribe some expiations for unintentionally killing a cat.

From the *Vishnu Smriti*:

> If he has unintentionally killed a mouse, or a **cat**, or an
>   ichneumon, or a frog, or a Duṇḍubha snake, or a large serpent—he must
>   fast for one day, and on the next day give a dish of milk, sesamum and
>   rice mixed together to a Brāhmaṇa and give him an iron hoe as his fee.

From the *Yājñavalkya Smriti*:

> (3.271) For killing a **cat**, an alligator, an ichneumon, a frog or
>   birds, one should drink milk for three days, or perform a quarter of
>   the Kṛcchra penance.

The *Vishnu Smriti* verse above says explicitly that that expiation is for the *unintentional* killing of a cat, so you should follow that.

Just go to a nearby temple and present a Purohit those two gifts mentioned in that verse.

Comment: What is krcchra penance?

Comment: @Vishalprabhulawande Here: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/30282/what-are-the-prajapatya-chandrayana-and-krcchra-penances