# Do scriptures allow Hindus to marry foreigners?

Tags: dharma, marriage, dharma-shastras

Do scriptures allow Hindus to marry foreigners, or non-Hindus of other races?

Inter-caste marriage has its restrictions, but what about interracial marriages?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, the Dharma Shastras explicitly forbid Hindus from marrying foreigners, otherwise known as *[Mlecchas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mleccha)*.

Here are some verses from the *Atri Smriti* that prohibit interracial marriages:

> 182. The purification for knowing [having sex with] a *Mleccha* woman consists in a Santapanam penance, or it is said, one may attain to
>      purification by performing a Taptakrcchra penance.
> 183. If a person lives with a wife known [who has had sex with] by a *Mleccha* man, he becomes purified by bathing with the cloth on and drinking clarified butter.
> 184. By cohabiting [living with and having sex with], unknowingly, with the women of the *Chandalas*, *Mlecchas* ... one is purified by a
>      Paraka.
> 185. **But if one knows them willingly, and procreates children with them, then he is degraded to the same caste as them**; there is no doubt
>      about it, for that man is born as her son.

So it is actually a huge sin to marry foreigners, since one becomes degraded to the caste of *Mleccha*.

[This](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/30282/what-are-the-prajapatya-chandrayana-and-krcchra-penances) answer explains some of the different types of penances for sins.

Comment: Its written that they will be degraded as there caste doesn't mean it's sin

Comment: AFAIK One does not get degraded for doing punya karma, degradation happens only after papa karma.