# Can a shudra male marry a mleccha female?

Tags: marriage, tradition, varna, mleccha, sampradaya

Does the answer differ with sāmpradaya?
Are mlecchas initiated into a traditional sāmpradaya still considered mlecchas?

Comment: Related question which has an answer already [Do scriptures allow Hindus to marry foreigners?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/31900/24460)

Comment: I have heard from a madhwa on quora that a mleccha who had undergone tapta mudra dharana is considered a shudra. Is that true? @Bingming

Comment: Taptamudrādhāraṇā can be done by person of any jāti or liṅga. I am not aware of any source which mentions that the one who undergoes this ritual becomes a Śūdra.

Answer (score 0):

As per vedas, term "arya" applies only to brahmaNa, kshatriya & vaishya and shudra is differentiated from arya :

> **atharva veda iv.20.4. :**
>
> *The thousand-eyed god shall put this plant into my right hand; with that do I see everyone, **the Shudra as well as the Arya**.*
>
> **Kathaka Samhita xxxiv.5 :**
>
> ***The Shudra and the Arya** quarrel about the skin. The gods and the demons quarrelled about the sun; the gods won it (the sun). (By this
> act of quarrelling with Shudras) the Arya makes the Arya Varna win,
> makes himself successful. The Arya shall be inside the .altar, the
> Shudra outside the altar. The skin shall be white, circular- the form
> of the sun.*

Even anuloma & pratiloma are referred as sat-shudra & asat-shudra as per brahmavaivartapurANa-brahmakhanDa-ch10 & manu X.41

> **manu X.41 :**
>
> 41. Six sons, begotten (by Aryans) on women of equal and the next lower castes (Anantara), have the duties of twice-born men; but all
>     those born in consequence of a violation (of the law) are, as regards
>     their duties, equal to Sudras.
>
> **brahmavaivartapurANa-brahmakhanDa-ch10 :** [image]

Those who are outside of above arya & shudra are referred as **dasyu** :

> **manu X 45**
> *All those tribes in this world, which are excluded from (the community of) those born from the mouth, the arms, the thighs, and the
> feet (of Brahman), **are called Dasyus**, whether they speak the
> language of the mlecchas or that of the Aryans.*

**There is a provision for shudra (asat-shudra) to marry a mleccha (dasyu) :**

> *32. A **dasyu begets on an Ayogava (woman)** a Sairandhra, who is skilled in adorning and attending (his master), who, (though) not a
> slave, lives like a slave, (or) subsists by snaring (animals).*