# Alternatives to doing Krcchra penances

Tags: scripture, vrata

In modern age doing proper [Krcchra penance](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/30282/what-are-the-prajapatya-chandrayana-and-krcchra-penances/30293#30293) is very tough and not always practical.  Are there any alternative to Krcchra penances suited to modern age recommended in the scriptures?  I have heard people saying a dip in holy Ganga river is equivalent to many Krcchra penances but I haven't found any authentic scriptural references validate it.  Please share if you know of any sort of procedure or Sadhana that is equivalent to doing a Krcchra penance.