What is the impact on Bhuloka due to non-performance of the Sandhya Rituals?
With increasing number of Brahmanas giving up their daily Sandhya Vandana rituals:

Does this directly impact the earthly species in general along with Suryadeva or only those missing their Sandhya?

Is further information available on the Mandeha Rakshasas who try to devour the sun during the sandhya periods?



Related -- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/21349

Edited the question to make it more specific. Thanks

When dvijas don't perform sandhyavandanam, mandeha rakshasas won't be pulled into one island(I forgot its name) as a result they start to increase asuric activities in the world. You can see people like ambedkarities and periyarities are spreading adharma in the past 100 years, most probably because dvijas stopped doing Sandhya in large numbers when they started going to British introduced schools

Thanks for the share. Yes, I think it's the same time when the performances of Sandhya reduced drastically, these anti-Sanatani forces became stronger, at least in the last century or so. Would be interested to know more about the island if you happen to find it.
